# android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART not works on android higher versions

Tags: android

android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART works fine on android 2.3,
but not working on higher version.......

I  have tried this link

"http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEMQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F18692571%2Fhow-it-works-warning-that-app-is-going-to-be-uninstalled&ei=cUaHUsmBOcaprAeJ84GIDg&usg=AFQjCNH-6Nn2-5nZsR19Zls5l3NKrVrvYg&sig2=EXpUvWEyxjhq-BZPjse8Sg&bvm=bv.56643336,d.bmk"

but problem not solved....

Comment: The behaviour has changed. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20701763/769265