# Android, How can I get my app is going to uninstall

Tags: android, uninstallation

I want to know that anything in Android that gives response to my App that App is going to uninstall from Phone?

I tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756180/ask-for-password-before-uninstalling-application) but its not working for me.

Thank you

Comment: Below link may help you. Please check it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279270/android-can-native-code-get-broadcast-intent-from-android-system/21337119#answer-21337119

Comment: Thank u Samir Bhatt :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know that anything in Android that gives response to my App that App is going to uninstall from Phone?

That is not possible, at least from Android SDK code. Nothing is called on your app when the process is being terminated.

Comment: Thank u Anatol for ur reply :)