# Uninstall application uninstallreceiver not called

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, uninstallation

After lots of google I have found some good solutions to find out uninstall receiver of application.I am referring [First Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692571/how-it-works-warning-that-app-is-going-to-be-uninstalled) and [Second Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699640/cant-get-receiver-when-the-app-uninstall/20701763?noredirect=1#comment32285791_20701763).

In Second link you can find [source code](http://dropbox.com/s/0bgbcfn0a0gfoe3/UninstallDetected.zip) of uninstalldetection created by dickfala.I have tried this code on my devices which has android 4.1.2 and 4.0.4 Os but whileing running the app on device I am not able to see logs of application in logcat and application just uninstalled from device.

I know too much discussion already done on this topic but I am not able to find any proper solution for it that's why I have asked this question.Anyone know please help me.

Comment: As I indicated in my answer (that you linked), this no longer works reliably in Android 4.0 and higher.

Comment: @DavidWasser ok..thank so much for your kind support.In future if you find any solution regarding it let me know.

Comment: If this is not for android 4.x, then how the AppLock get the intent for this?

Comment: Why do you need this? Maybe we can find a workaround for your goal?