# Want to perform some task (Like Logging on server) during uninstallation of an android App?

Tags: android, android-intent

My requirement is same as [How can an app detect that it's going to be uninstalled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18692571/4070142)

So i am implementing it in exactly same way as answer suggested in the above linked question https://stackoverflow.com/a/18816716/4070142...

I am running it on Android 4.4 (Kitkat). But i am not receiving the QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART intent in my BroadcastReceiver. I am registering the broadcastreceiver properly in manifest file. Is it problem of android version or something else... Any help?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699640/cant-get-receiver-when-the-app-uninstall/20701763#20701763

Comment: Asking the same question again isn't going to get you a better answer.